# Excel: Reference an external workbook using named range

Tags: excel

I'm trying to reference data from a table in another worksheet. I'm able to get it to work when I used cell numbers but can't get it to work when I use named ranges.

Works:

```
=SUM('/Path/To/File/[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1'!A2:A5)
```

Works when source workbook is open:

```
=SUM(Book1.xlsx!Table1[Column1])
```

Doesn't work when source workbook is closed:

```
=SUM('/Path/To/File/Book1.xlsx'!Table1[Column1])
```

I would like to use the named range due to the source table constantly being updated with values. Lastly, I'm using Excel for Mac which could be the issue but wanted to confirm. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `Table1[Column1]` really a named range? I think that's a table reference instead.  What you can do, is open the `Book1.xlsx` file, and link to it in your worksheet.  Then you'll get the reference that works, i.e. the second formula you posted.  If you then close the source workbook, that formula *should* update with the proper reference.  Does it not do that?

Comment: Whoops, I am using a table reference. I also tried to do a named range but I get the same issue. I'm not sure how to link it the way you're talking about but the formula on the bottom is the updated formula that is created once I close the source workbook.